# Trouble opening audio files stored on S3 in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I stored like 300 GB of audio data (mp3/wav mostly) on Amazon S3 and am trying to access it in a SageMaker notebook instance to do some data transformations. I'm trying to use either torchaudio or librosa to load a file as a waveform. torchaudio expects the file path as the input, librosa can either use a file path or file-like object. I tried using s3fs to get the url to the file but torchaudio doesn't recognize it as a file. And apparently SageMaker has problems installing librosa so I can't use that. What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps, you want to download the file locally and read using `torchaudio.load`? If you use boto3 and other connectors, they are basically the same: download and feed the content.

Comment: I think some code, showing what you have done, would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using SageMaker for this, but for anybody else having similar problems, I solved this by opening the file using s3fs and writing it to a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`. This gave me a file path that I could pass into either `torchaudio.load` or `librosa.core.load`. This was also important because I wanted the extra resampling functionality of `librosa.core.load`, but it doesn't accept file-like objects for loading mp3s.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has this issue and has to use Sagemaker, I found installing librosa using the following:

`!conda install -y -c conda-forge librosa`

rather than via pip allowed me to use it in Sagemaker.